# Extract XML Tag and append to a specific location in another xml using Shell Script

Tags: xml, shell, awk, sed, xmllint

I have two license xml files: `a-license.xml` and `b-license.xml`. The format of both the license files is same. I want to merge them into a single file.

Sample Input:

File a-license.xml contains

```
   <company-license>
   <generator></generator>
   <customer></customer>
   <orderid></orderid>
   <expiration></expiration>
   <license>
      <module>A</module>
      <license_key>xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx</license_key>
   </license>
   </company-license>
```

File b-license.xml contains

```
  <company-license>  
   <generator></generator>
   <customer></customer>
   <orderid></orderid>
   <expiration></expiration>
   <license>
      <module>B</module>
      <license_key>yyyy-yyyy-yyyy</license_key>
   </license>
   </company-license>
```

Desired output should be something like

```
  <company-license> 
   <generator></generator>
   <customer></customer>
   <orderid></orderid>
   <expiration></expiration>
   <license>
      <module>A</module>
      <license_key>xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx</license_key>
   </license>
   <license>
      <module>B</module>
      <license_key>yyyy-yyyy-yyyy</license_key>
   </license>
   </company-license>
```

I want to extract `<license>` tag from `a-license.xml` and append it below the `<license>` tag of `b-license.xml`.

How can I do this?

Comment: You're almost certainly just not quoting your variable. Try `echo "$license_tag"` not `echo $license_tag`. If that's not it, add more info explaining what you've tried, in what way tit's failing, and sample input/expected output that we could test a solution against.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion @Ed Morton. I have just updated the question.

Comment: Do those ticks REALLY exist in your files? If not then remove them

Comment: No they don't.This is the first time I am posting a question on stackoverflow and pretty new to writing a shell script as well.Thanks for highlighting.

Comment: I see you have modified your input to include more lines. That is a VERY important change from your original post and makes it a completely different question. Really THINK now if there's anything else you should add to your example before anyone spends time trying to help you with your new problem.

Comment: you may want to consider XML tools for this and not awk or sed, which are both great utilities, just not meant for this. there are many scriptable ways to utlize xsl or xquery from the command line. I like `xqilla` for something short of sweet.

Comment: @EdMorton Yes I get your point. No more changes. Will keep in mind the next time when I post a question or answer someone.Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -n '1,/<license>/{/<license>/d;p;}' a-license.xml > new-license.xml
sed -n '/<license>/,/<\/license>/p' a-license.xml >> new-license.xml
sed -n '/<license>/,/<\/company-license>/p' b-license.xml >> new-license.xml
```

or shorter:

```
sed -n '1,/<\/license>/p' a-license.xml > new-license.xml
sed -n '/<license>/,$p' b-license.xml >> new-license.xml
```

Output to file new-license.xml:

```
<company-license>
   <generator></generator>
   <customer></customer>
   <orderid></orderid>
   <expiration></expiration>
   <license>
      <module>A</module>
      <license_key>xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx</license_key>
   </license>
   <license>
      <module>B</module>
      <license_key>yyyy-yyyy-yyyy</license_key>
   </license>
   </company-license>
```

Comment: I am Sorry I am new to Stackoverflow and to shell scripting with xml parsing as well.I worked out for me but there is a minor error.The `<company-license>` tag is not appending properly.I did not specify that previously.I have updated the I/P and O/P file.So currently my O/P with the command that you specified looks something like:

Comment: `<company-license> 
   <generator></generator>
   <customer></customer>
   <orderid></orderid>
   <expiration></expiration>
   <license>
      <module>A</module>
      <license_key>xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx</license_key>
   </license>                                                
   <**/company-license**>                                                                                              <license>
      <module>B</module>
      <license_key>yyyy-yyyy-yyyy</license_key>
   </license>
   </company-license>` It would be great if I could get rid of **`</company-license>`** in the middle.

Comment: It gives an error `sed: 1: "1,/<license>/{/<license ...": extra characters at the end of p command`

Comment: Sorry, I had written this code for use with GNU sed. I've updated by answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{print;next} /<license>/{f=1} f' fileA fileB
<generator></generator>
<customer></customer>
<orderid></orderid>
<expiration></expiration>
<license>
   <module>A</module>
   <license_key>xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx</license_key>
</license>
<license>
   <module>B</module>
   <license_key>yyyy-yyyy-yyyy</license_key>
</license>
```

Comment: I am sorry again for the confusion but the file consists of another tag at the top `<company-license>` and it ends right after `<license></license>`.Something like `<company-license>..........<license></license></company-license>`

Comment: The command which you specified works but it does not append in the correct order.

Comment: I don't know what that means. The output looks exactly like the output you originally requested, order and all.